# Docker for Windows 10 and Volume

Tags: windows, docker, docker-volume, docker-for-windows

All,

I'm learning Docker on my Windows Desktop 10. Windows is Pro edition and Docker is  18.09.

When I run the below -

> docker run -it nanoserver/iis  -v
>   C:\ProgramData\Docker\volumes\vol01:C:\vol01 cmd.exe

I get the below error -

> docker: Error response from daemon: container
>   5a1229eca277cbddeefd5637e69554458003c54be3f30cc44ca41c8fa68a4a94
>   encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system
>   call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2) [Event Detail: 
>   Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] extra info:
>   {"CommandLine":"-v C:\ProgramData\Docker\volumes\vol01:C:\vol01
>   cmd.exe","WorkingDirectory":"C:\","EmulateConsole":true,"CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[63,237]}.

The volume does exist -

> docker volume inspect vol01
>
> [
>       {
>           "CreatedAt": "2018-12-26T03:01:01-05:00",
>           "Driver": "local",
>           "Labels": {},
>           "Mountpoint": "C:\ProgramData\Docker\volumes\vol01\_data",
>           "Name": "vol01",
>           "Options": {},
>           "Scope": "local"
>       } ]

I don't know what is wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
rgn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare volumes **before** image name for `docker run`. Consider:

```
docker run -it -v C:\ProgramData\Docker\volumes\vol01:C:\vol01 nanoserver/iis cmd.exe
```